# Bit shift operator precedence in C

Tags: c, operator-precedence

the bit shift operator in C is not operating as I expect, which without doubt is my misunderstanding, but can someone explain what's happening?

```
unsigned char in = 155;
unsigned char res;

res = (in << 6) >> 7;
```

should be the same as

```
res = in << 6;
res = res >> 7; // can also use res >>= 7;
```

but it's not.

The first result is:

```
in  = 10011011
res = 01001101
```

The second one (as expected):

```
in  = 10011011
res = 00000001
```

So it looks like in the first instance, it's operating each shift on the original data, instead of operating the first shift, then operating the second shift on the first result. Ideas?

Comment: @keshlam That's an answer.

Comment: read more about C's int promotion rules [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast)

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion`. See OWAP's [C-Based Toolchain Hardening](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/C-Based_Toolchain_Hardening) to catch these kind of issues early.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calculations are done in `int`s. In the second case, you're assigning to `res`, which will truncate to 8 bits, before shifting back. In the first case you aren't, so the truncation doesn't occur and the high bits are preserved and shifted back down.

Comment: to explain why the compiler is operating on ints: integer promotion rules.

Comment: It's also possible that the compiler "optimized" your <<6 and >>7 into a single >>1. It would be considered a glitch for a compiler to do this, but it's far from unimaginable.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, for Bitwise shift operators, Each of the operands shall have **integer** type. you **should not** use **char** type.

you will find the difference if you do this:

```
res = in << 6;
printf("%p %p \n",res,(in << 6));
```