# left shifting in between two different unsinged integer values

Tags: c++, c

when am I applying left shifting to 1 by 4 bit as **1<<4** it printing **16** as the value but if I will apply shifting like **1<<4 + 1<<3** then it printing **256** as a result,
I am not getting, how many shifting is apply and how it is working?
but according to me answer should be **24** by applying **4** left shift + **3** shift

Comment: Related: [Bit shift operator precedence in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497935/bit-shift-operator-precedence-in-c) and [Operator precedence (bitwise & lower than ==)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685072/operator-precedence-bitwise-lower-than)

Answer (score 3):

```
1 << 4 + 1 << 3
```

Is actually interpreted as

```
(1 << ( 4 + 1 )) << 3
```

See?

```
1 << 5 --> 32
32 << 3 --> 256
```

When in doubt, use more parentheses!

```
(1 << 5) + (1 << 3) --> 24
```

Comment: Shift operators act like multiplication or division, so it's easy to assume that they should bind more tightly than `+` and `-` -- but they don't.